# how to convert class component to function component?

Tags: reactjs, react-class-based-component, scroll-snap

I am new to React and I am trying to convert this code below to a function component, but it doesn't work, I have never used class components. Could anyone help me to convert it?
Thanks in advance.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import ScrollSnap from 'scroll-snap'

import './styles.css'

class App extends React.Component {
  container = React.createRef()

  bindScrollSnap() {
    const element = this.container.current
    new ScrollSnap(element, {
      snapDestinationY: '90%',
    }).bind()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.bindScrollSnap()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.container}>
      </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Replace `createRef` with `useRef` which is the functional hook to be used in functional components.
2. Replace `componentDidMount` with `useEffect()` with an empty array as dependency array, which basically runs that code once, on mount.

```
const App = () => {
  const containerRef = React.useRef(null);

  const bindScrollSnap = () => {
    new ScrollSnap(containerRef , {
      snapDestinationY: '90%',
    }).bind()
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    bindScrollSnap();
  }, []);
  return <div ref={containerRef}></div>
}
```

Comment: `TypeError: this.listenerElement.addEventListener is not a function`  gives exactly the same error which I got when I tried to convert it too. Here is the entire code:
`
const containerRef = React.useRef(null);

  const bindScrollSnap = () => {
    new ScrollSnap(containerRef, {
      snapDestinationY: "90%",
    }).bind();
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    bindScrollSnap();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
      <Home data={data} />
      <Category />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
`

Comment: `scroll-snap` expects an element not a ref. try to find a different library that works with react

Comment: Yeah, I have found another library. Thanks anyway.